# Hiding and getting the data from one page to another page using tapestry and java

Tags: java, tapestry

Im working on a project in which I have to do the following.

I have a form that has some properties like address, personal information.

I want to use the few of the properties in the previous page to show in the other page as per few validations. I can show the properties of one page into other page by using tapestry(though I'm new to it).

I want to know if we can do the validations on the Java side in the service class, and if it is possible, how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data between pages by multiple ways, most commonly used way is to use `@Persist` scoped `@Property`

[here](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/state/passingbypersist) is a complete example of it

for validation there is a method that gets called before action phase, [this](http://tapestry.apache.org/forms-and-validation.html) document describes it well